# place id in html tag used in php

Tags: php, html

I have a code in php:

```
<?php

echo '<td id="A01" width="12%">'.$row['CASE_NO'].'</td>';

>?
```

I put a id in the tag but when i used it in jquery its not working. what i am doing wrong?

OR

If there is anyway to do something like that?

```
echo '<td id="A01" width="12%">'<?php.$row['CASE_NO'].>?'</td>';
```

I know this is wrong but something like that so that i can use the id?

jquery:

```
$('#righticon').click(function(){
$('#A01').hide();
});
```

**Edit:**

ok this is my jquery function:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $('#righticon').click(function()
  { 

    $('#A01').hide();
});
});
```

my php code

```
while($row = oci_fetch_array($query))
{
// we are running a while loop to print all the rows in a table

echo'<tr>';
echo '<td id="A01" width="12%">'.$row['CASE_NO'].'</td>';
echo'</tr>';
}
```

want i am doing is that when i click on the next button i want to hide this above  value.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where's your jquery code? Also, the first echo statement is correct, the second is not because you can't use the php open tag inside php

Comment: So what's not working? Is this jquery code inside the `document.ready` function? `$('#A01')` is a valid selector and would match the ID. Make sure you only have one `id=AO1`. It's been a while since I've tried but `hide()` on table cells may be problematic cross-browser.

Comment: my whole function is: <script>$('#righticon').click(function(){
$('#A01').hide();
});</script>

when i click on the button nothing happens.

Comment: 1. include jquery 2. wrap js in `document.ready`;

Answer (score 1):

Your first line of code looks correct, php does not care if you use single or double quotes. 
Sounds like jquery might not be referenced correctly. Try just plain old java script and see if it works then move on from there.

```
<script>
function getValue()
{
  var x = document.getElementById("A01");
  console.log(x.innerHTML);
}
</script>

<h1 onclick="getValue()">Click here to log</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the comments you mentioned your jQuery code is simply in a script:

`<script>$('#righticon').click(function(){ $('#A01').hide(); });</script>`

Try using the jQuery document ready function, which executes your code after the html has properly loaded. Otherwise this code is executed before any html

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#righticon').click(function(){ $('#A01').hide(); });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Show us what you're trying. The devil is in the details and you're only giving us snippets

Comment: You have the `id="A01"` set in your while loop, meaning there will be more than one. `id`s need to be unique. Do you have an element with the `id="righticon"` ?

Comment: style="display:none" is also not wroking in echo otherwise i have used that.

Comment: You may need to try this without a table, or using `visbility: hidden;` Table cells don't work like block-level elements